# How to get the buffer type of the current buffer?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I'm writing mapping, and I want to decide whether I have to do additional actions when current buffer type is a drawer called `Fern`, here is my command currently

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent> ;
            \ <CR>:Fern %:h:h -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%<CR>
```

What I want to do is like:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent><expr> ;
        \ buffertype(current_buffer)=='Fern'? ":w" : ""
        \ ."\<CR>:Fern %:h:h -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%\<CR>"
```

So what should be the substitute of pseudocode `buffertype(current_buffer)` here? Do we really have function alike?

Comment: Buffer type? Are you talking about file type?

Comment: @BLayer: I probably use the wrong phrase, I want to detect my current is currently inside the drawer. So it's called file type?

Comment: Let's see. Run `:set ft?` ... if it shows 'Fern' that's the one.

Comment: @BLayer: The plug-in I'm using is called Fern, and I'm not sure about whether in vim we can create our own file type. Can we?

Comment: Yes. For instance, nerdtree buffers have file types like `nerdtree` or something like that.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Comment: Sure...but did you try it? Can't be 100% sure until it's tested. :)

Comment: @BLayer: It output: `filetype=fern`, I think you are correct!

Comment: Okay, excellent. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @B Layer's kindly comments, I found that what I should detect is the **file type**, not buffer type, of the current window where the cursor at.

The final result is:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent><expr> ;
            \ (&filetype!='fern' ? ":w\<CR>" : "")
            \ .":Fern %:h:h -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%\<CR>"
```

(and it should be `!=fern`, not `==fern`, an logical error compare to my OP)

**Update**:

To also open the drawer on [No Name] file, i.e. `filetype=` nothing, we have:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent><expr> ;
            \ (&filetype!='fern' && &filetype!=''? ":w\<CR>" : "")
            \ .":Fern %:h:h -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%\<CR>"
```

or this tricky `<bar><bar>` version:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent><expr> ;
            \ (&filetype=="fern"<bar><bar>&filetype==""? "" : ":w\<CR>")
            \ .":Fern %:h:h -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%\<CR>"
```

The second one is tricky that if you use `||` it will show `trailing characters` error. In theory the second one is faster by short-circuiting.